# Can`t drop the column, because another column was recently deleted

Tags: google-bigquery

I deleted the ColumnA at the table and want to drop the ColumnB.

`ALTER TABLE Project.Schema.Table   DROP COLUMN  ColumnB;`

But i got an error

```
Column `ColumnA` was recently deleted in the table `Table`. Deleted column name is reserved for up to the time travel duration, use a different column name instead.
```

Why I can`t delete ColumnB? How to do this? Only recreate the table?

Comment: Hi @Novitskiy Denis, If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs due to the [Time Travel](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/time-travel) feature of BigQuery which enables recovery of data that is changed or deleted up to 7 days later.This feature maintains 7 days of history, including metadata history. There are two workaround possible for this issue:

- Wait for 7 days and then retry to drop the other column.
- Drop the table and  recreate using a temporary table.

This issue has been raised in this [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/129248927). You can “STAR” the issue to receive automatic updates and give it traction by referring to this [link](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue).

Comment: so i can delete only one column in 7 days in one table?

Comment: Hi @Novitskiy Denis, if you perform any alter operation on the table, then for next alter operation, you need to wait for 7 days as mentioned in the documentation.